# Python selenium iframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to switch to iframe in captcha, but I get this error 
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//iframe" is: [object HTMLIFrameElement]. It should be an element.
I tryed with switcing to Iiframe, but it doesnt work, I find iframe with inspecting element, but I can not find element when I run the script, also I added explicit wait, time sleep, but it still doesn't work
here is html code

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Access to this page has been denied.</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            color: #000;
        }

        a {
            color: #c5c5c5;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .container {
            align-items: center;
            display: flex;
            flex: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .container > div {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .container > div > div {
            display: flex;
            width: 80%;
        }

        .customer-logo-wrapper {
            padding-top: 2rem;
            flex-grow: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .customer-logo {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .customer-logo > img {
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
            max-height: 50px;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .page-title-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 2;
        }

        .page-title {
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }

        .content-wrapper {
            flex-grow: 5;
        }

        .content {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .page-footer-wrapper {
            align-items: center;
            flex-grow: 0.2;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #c5c5c5;
            font-size: 70%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>

<script src="/rw7M6iAV/captcha/PXrw7M6iAV/captcha.js?a=c&amp;m=0&amp;u=266c5db0-19e6-11ea-8150-878a39a29362&amp;v="></script><style type="text/css">.px-loader-wrapper {    display: flex;}@keyframes loadingEffect {    0% {        background-position: 0;    }    100% {        background-position: 60vw;    }}.px-inner-loading-area {    width: 310px;    height: 30px;    animation-name: loadingEffect;    animation-duration: 1.2s;    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    animation-timing-function: ease;    animation-fill-mode: forwards;    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F6F6F6 8%, #F0F0F0 18%, #F6F6F6 33%);}.px-loading-area {    width: 310px;    height: 30px;    margin: 0;    ;}</style><script src="/rw7M6iAV/init.js"></script><a tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" href="/organization/waldeck-associates?_pxhc=1575828688573" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;"></a></head>
<body>
<section class="container">
<div class="customer-logo-wrapper">
<div class="customer-logo">
<img src="" alt="Logo">
</div>
</div>
<div class="page-title-wrapper">
<div class="page-title">
<h1>Please verify you are a human</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="content">
<div id="px-captcha" role="main"><style>@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
            #px-captcha {
                position: relative;
                right: 32px;
            }
        }</style><iframe style="display: block; width: 310px; height: 100px; border: 0; padding:0; margin: 0; -moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;" token="efbbf8834a03575dcd9c41ce37a32800bac150d7be5c1b3bf3a953f0879cfc3caa53da776440a3d731e03394daec916c92fe9416ba7947d3cea7370b970a551d"></iframe></div>
<p>
Access to this page has been denied because we believe you are using automation tools to browse the
website.
</p>
<p>
This may happen as a result of the following:
</p>
<ul>
<li>
Javascript is disabled or blocked by an extension (ad blockers for example)
</li>
<li>
Your browser does not support cookies
</li>
</ul>
<p>
Please make sure that Javascript and cookies are enabled on your browser and that you are not blocking
them from loading.
</p>
<p>
Reference ID: #266c5db0-19e6-11ea-8150-878a39a29362
</p>
<div id="px-block-form-wrapper"><div><style>#px-block-form-wrapper{width:400px;position:absolute;bottom:0;left:calc(50% - 200px)}#px-block-toggle-button{height:20px;background:#fff;color:#000;border-radius:3px;padding:10px;cursor:pointer;font-size:13px;text-align:center;width:270px;border:1px solid #000;font-weight:900;margin-left:75px;text-decoration:underline}#px-block-form{background:#fff;border:1px solid;border-color:#404040;color:#000;border-radius:3px;height:265px;font-size:12px}button#px-form-close{float:right;background:0 0;border:none;color:#fff;font-size:18px;cursor:pointer}button#px-form-submit{position:absolute;bottom:10px;background:#404040;border:none;width:100px;border-radius:3px;height:25px;color:#fff;right:20px;cursor:pointer}button#px-form-submit:disabled{background:#ddd;cursor:not-allowed;color:#000}div#px-form{color:#000;padding:15px}div#px-form-head{padding:10px;font-size:14px;background:#404040;color:#fff}div#px-form textarea{margin:-5px 0 0 4px;width:300px;height:36px}div#px-form div{margin-bottom:6px}#px-form-thank-you{background:#fff;color:#000;border:1px solid;border-color:#404040;border-radius:3px;height:54px;padding:5px 10px;text-align:center;width:330px;margin-left:35px}#px-form-thank-you div{font-size:15px;margin-top:14px}#px-form-thank-you span.checkmark{margin-right:8px;color:green;font-size:20px}div#px-form form h4{margin:8px 4px}@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){#px-block-form-wrapper{width:97%;position:relative;left:3%;z-index:10}#px-block-toggle-button{height:20px;background:#fff;color:#000;padding:3px;cursor:pointer;font-size:13px;text-align:center;width:94%;border:none;font-weight:900;text-decoration:underline;margin-left:0;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:10px;width:initial}#px-block-form{background:#fff;border:1px solid;border-color:#404040;color:#000;border-radius:3px;height:250px;font-size:12px}button#px-form-close{float:right;background:0 0;border:none;color:#fff;font-size:18px;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;right:15px;padding:0;bottom:6px}button#px-form-submit{position:absolute;bottom:10px;background:#404040;border:none;width:100px;border-radius:3px;height:25px;color:#fff;right:20px;cursor:pointer;font-size:13px}button#px-form-submit:disabled{background:#ddd;cursor:not-allowed;color:#000}div#px-form{color:#000;padding:15px}div#px-form-head{padding:10px;font-size:14px;background:#404040;color:#fff;position:relative}div#px-form textarea{margin:-5px 0 0 4px;width:90%;height:36px}div#px-form div{margin-bottom:6px}#px-form-thank-you{background:#fff;color:#000;border:1px solid;border-color:#404040;border-radius:3px;height:54px;padding:5px 10px;text-align:center;width:94%;margin-left:0}#px-form-thank-you div{font-size:15px;margin-top:14px}#px-form-thank-you span.checkmark{margin-right:8px;color:green;font-size:20px}div#px-form form h4{margin:8px 4px}.container{display:block;position:relative}.container .content-wrapper{padding-bottom:40px}.container .page-footer-wrapper{position:fixed;bottom:0}.container .content-wrapper .content{margin:0 auto}}</style><div id="px-block-toggle-button" onclick="_pxToggleOpenForm()" hidden="">Report an issue</div><div id="px-block-form"><div id="px-form-head"><span>Experiencing issues? Let us know:</span> <button onclick="_pxToggleOpenForm(!0)" id="px-form-close">X</button></div><div id="px-form"><form><div style="display:none"><input onchange="_pxItemSelected()" type="radio" id="opt0" name="px-report-reason" value="-1"> <label for="opt0">I’m a bot</label></div><div><input onchange="_pxItemSelected()" type="radio" id="opt1" name="px-report-reason" value="1"> <label for="opt1">I don’t see any challenge</label></div><div><input onchange="_pxItemSelected()" type="radio" id="opt2" name="px-report-reason" value="2"> <label for="opt2">I keep solving the challenge</label></div><div><input onchange="_pxItemSelected()" type="radio" id="opt3" name="px-report-reason" value="3"> <label for="opt3">Other (please elaborate)</label></div><h4>Additional Information:</h4><textarea id="px-form-free-text" placeholder="Experiencing other issues?"></textarea></form><button disabled="disabled" id="px-form-submit" onclick="_pxSubmitForm()">Send</button></div></div><div hidden="" id="px-form-thank-you"><div><span class="checkmark">✓</span><span>Thank you for the feedback</span></div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="page-footer-wrapper">
<div class="page-footer">
<p>
Powered by
<a href="https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked">PerimeterX</a>
, Inc.
</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<script>
    window._pxAppId = 'PXrw7M6iAV';
    window._pxJsClientSrc = '/rw7M6iAV/init.js';
    window._pxFirstPartyEnabled = true;
    window._pxVid = '';
    window._pxUuid = '266c5db0-19e6-11ea-8150-878a39a29362';
    window._pxHostUrl = '/rw7M6iAV/xhr';
</script>

<script>
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = '/rw7M6iAV/captcha/PXrw7M6iAV/captcha.js?a=c&m=0&u=266c5db0-19e6-11ea-8150-878a39a29362&v=';
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    p.insertBefore(s, null);
    if (true) {
        s.onerror = function () {
            s = document.createElement('script');
            var suffixIndex = '/rw7M6iAV/captcha/PXrw7M6iAV/captcha.js?a=c&m=0&u=266c5db0-19e6-11ea-8150-878a39a29362&v='.indexOf('captcha.js');
            var temperedBlockScript = '/rw7M6iAV/captcha/PXrw7M6iAV/captcha.js?a=c&m=0&u=266c5db0-19e6-11ea-8150-878a39a29362&v='.substring(suffixIndex);
            s.src = '//captcha.px-cdn.net/PXrw7M6iAV/' + temperedBlockScript;
            p.parentNode.insertBefore(s, p);
        };
    }
</script>



</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception itself says that the selector is incorrect. Try to use absolute xpath while selecting the iFrame. Absolute xpath for captcha iframe always works for me.

Also it woulbe be great if you can share your automation code

Comment: it still doesn't work. You need to iterate throught pags to get this captcha. I will try to add the code, but I think only way is to define coordinates

Comment: Can you share any video to show the exact behavior? It would be easier if you can share a link of your page. Also do try with coordinates if you fill it will help.